# Want to run jQuery code in wordpress plugin on every wordpress site page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I am trying to make a wordpress plugin that will run a jQuery script when I activate plugin and my jquery code is below:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    jQuery(window).scroll(function() {

    if(jQuery(this).scrollTop() != 0) {
        jQuery("#toTop").fadeIn("slow");    
    } else {
        jQuery("#toTop").fadeOut("slow");
    }
});

jQuery("#toTop").click(function() {
    jQuery("body,html").animate({scrollTop:0},1000);
});


});
```

Please tell me wordpress plugin code which will run this query on every wordpress site page when I activate plugin.

Answer (score 0):

to insert js into the footer of every page, try;

```
<?php
function myJScript(){
// echo js here, or output it like below..
?>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    jQuery(window).scroll(function() {

    if(jQuery(this).scrollTop() != 0) {
        jQuery("#toTop").fadeIn("slow");    
    } else {
        jQuery("#toTop").fadeOut("slow");
    }
  });

  jQuery("#toTop").click(function() {
    jQuery("body,html").animate({scrollTop:0},1000);
  });
});
</script>
<?php
} // end function

// call function myJScript in the footer of every page
add_action('wp_footer', 'myJScript');
```

Comment: sorry, what do you want in the bottom right corner..?

Comment: my this div:

<div id="totop"></div>